# Triefen als starkes oder schwaches Verb

Tags: verb, conjugation

> Er troff vor Nässe
>
> Er triefte vor Nässe

Was ist der Bedeutungsunterschied zwischen den zwei Beugungen und was ist am angemessensten?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*triefen* ist eines der wenigen Verben, die sowohl stark als auch schwach gebeugt werden dürfen (Das hat möglicherweise damit zu tun, dass das Verb gerade einen sprachlichen Wandel von stark zu schwach durchmacht). Da es sich demnach um dasselbe Verb handelt, gibt es auch keinen Bedeutungsunterschied.

Meinem Sprachgefühl nach hört sich "troff" ein bißchen altmodisch an.

Ngrams gibt der starken Form deutlich den Vorzug (und widerspricht damit meiner Annahme des Wandels zum schwachen Verb), aber erfasst natürlich nur Schriftdeutsch (ich denke, da ist die starke Beugung eher angebracht als in der Umgangssprache)

[image].